# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/AbstractType

Tags: cassandra, hive

Hi I am getting above error on running the following script. Could you please help me what is wrong with this.

```
add jar /users/hddvmktg/hivejars/hive-cassandra-1.2.9.jar;
add jar /users/hddvmktg/hivejars/cassandra-all-1.2.9.jar;
add jar /users/hddvmktg/hivejars/cassandra-thrift-1.2.9.jar;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mktg_contact_general_info_comp_hive_incr 
        (
        person_party_id string,
        org_party_id            string, 
        last_transaction_dt     string,
        last_source_system      string,
        introduction_source_system     string,
        introduction_date       string,
        name_prefix             string)
        STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler'
        WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("cassandra.columns.mapping" = ":person_party_id,:org_party_id,:last_transaction_dt,:last_source_system,:introduction_source_system,:introduction_date,:name_prefix",
        "cassandra.host"="127.0.0.1","cassandra.port" = "9170","cassandra.cf.name" = "mkds_cmc_cf")
        TBLPROPERTIES ("cassandra.ks.name" = "mkds_cmc");
```